# How automatic NDB caching works?

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, app-engine-ndb, quota

My website is movies catalog. Once user log in, I show him/her the latest movie added to my database:

```
movies = Movies.query()
movies = movies.order(-Movies.added)
movie = movies.get(keys_only = True) // get_latest_movie_id
```

Is it cached (movies are added to the database weekly, so it should be cached)? How to verify that (i.e. what is memcache key)? 
Yesterday about 1000 users visited my site and I've got

> OverQuotaError: The API call datastore_v3.RunQuery() required more
>   quota than is available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NDB only caches gets by key. I suspect that in your example code `movies` is a query, and NDB doesn't cache queries, you'll need to do that yourself.

Comment: I've updated the code. So, this is not cached, right? Is `Movies.get_by_id(movie_id)` cached? Where to read more about NDB caching?

Comment: The code you've posted won't use memcache. Movies.get_by_id(movie_id) will. There's a whole page in the docs about caching: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache