# Use of memcache with NDB

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm going from db to ndb and I have a little doubt.

I've read the [Caching](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache) docs but I need a clarification or a confirmation: with db I was using memcache to save my "views" and avoid hitting the datastore. NDB "caches" the entities reads and writes, but, also any read I can do?

E.g.: items = Item.query().fetch(100) gives me my items. This query is cached by NDB automatically? If two users wants to see the items in my list, the second read will hit the NDB cache?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How automatic NDB caching works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654159/how-automatic-ndb-caching-works)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NDB only caches get() calls, where you fetch entities by key.

Queries are not cached.

Comment: Again, thanks @dragonx. So I must still manually use memcache for GQL and fetchs